# Discord.js Unknown Guild when removing all roles from a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to remove all roles from a user. This code worked yesterday but I got on today and it has broken somehow.

```
message.member.removeRoles(message.member.roles.filter(role => role.name!='Admin' && role.name!='@everyone'));
```

The stack trace:

```
(node:27392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Guild
at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\nnova\Documents\Discord\Bots\repbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:71:65)
at then (C:\Users\nnova\Documents\Discord\Bots\repbot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:27392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

(node:27392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Nowhere in the stack trace does it even reference my code...

Does anyone know what is happening? I've spent an hour searching and trying to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its a bug with either discord API or discord.js. Fixed by a completely unrelated line of code being changed. Don't try to reference your guild using client.guilds.filter(...) it causes all sorts of issues that can only be fixed by kicking your bot and having him rejoin the server

Answer (score 0):

FIX: There was an error: DiscordAPIError[10004]: Unknown Guild

After so, so many hours of debugging and head-scratching, our team finally fixed the issue with the error listed above. Actually, you have to add a bot to your server. Then, you can use your discord token to make the API calls and it will work fine.

Follow the following steps to resolve your issues:

1. Go to the Discord Developer Portal (https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro)
2. Go to Applications (from the sidebar)
   Click on your application
3. Go to OAuth2 (from the right sidebar)
4. Go to URL Generator in OAuth2

5.You will be shown a screen like this now:
[image]

6. Now, click on "bot" option and a drop down menu will be shown to you
7. Select Administrator now as shown in the picture

[image]

8. Now, scroll to the very, very bottom of the page, and you will be given a URL (GENERATED URL).
9. Search this URL in the browser.
10. Follow the next steps. And add a bot with admin privileges to your server. Now, your APIs will work